# Remote Desktop Connection fails. Can't enable RDP

Tags: remote-desktop

Connecting Remote Desktop to my android phone fails - newest version 12.
I used RDP many times before I got Windows 10. That was back when Teamviewer was free.
The firewall is set. RDP is turned on. When I go to enable remote desktop it never sticks. It stays off.
I've looked at the policies and they all seem correct.
Thanks for your help, Lamar

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've been asked for more specifics. Goal: Use Microsoft Remote Desktop between my Windows 10 laptop and my android phone. When I type in phone's 192.168.0.04 RDP says: Remote Desktop can't find the computer "192.168.0.N". This might mean that "192.168.0.N" does not belong to the specified network. Verify the computer name and domain that you are trying to connect to. 
I verified the firewall allows RDP, the policy allows it, and did a network map to pinpoint the IP addresses. In years past I used RDP. 
Any help is appreciated. I am open to using another option. Thanks